# How to get the Taylor series of implicit functions

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, series-expansion

Given that the equation $x+\frac{1}{2} y^{2} +\frac{1}{2} z+\sin (z)=0$ can determine an implicit function $z(x,y)$ at {0, 0}, I now need to expand the implicit function $z(x,y)$ to a fourth-order Taylor series at {0, 0}. How can I do it?

```
x + 1/2 y^2 + 1/2 z[x, y] + Sin[z[x, y]] == 0
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`AsymptoticSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AsymptoticSolve) for this purpose:

```
AsymptoticSolve[x+1/2y^2+1/2z+Sin[z]==0,{z,0},{{x,y},{0,0},4}]
```

> {{z -> -((2 x)/3) - (8 x^3)/243 - y^2/3 - (4 x^2 y^2)/81}}

Comment: The question arises: how to translate the Maple's code `mtaylor(solve(x + 1/2*y^2 + 1/2*z + sin(z) = 0, z), [x = 3, y = -2], 2)` which results in $${\it RootOf} \left( 10+2\,\sin \left( {\it \_Z} \right) +{\it \_Z}
 \right) -2\,{\frac {x-3}{2\,\cos \left( {\it RootOf} \left( 10+2\,
\sin \left( {\it \_Z} \right) +{\it \_Z} \right)  \right) +1}}+4\,{
\frac {y+2}{2\,\cos \left( {\it RootOf} \left( 10+2\,\sin \left( {\it 
\_Z} \right) +{\it \_Z} \right)  \right) +1}} $$ and after that `evalf(allvalues(%))` produces $13.60567714- 3.091009870\,x+ 6.182019740\,y,...$
  in Wolfram Language?

Comment: @user: if you first evaluate `s1 = z /. Solve[10 + 2 Sin[z] + z == 0, z, Reals]` in *Mathematica*, you'll notice that you get three real solutions. The third one is the one you need to reproduce the Maple solution: `z /. First @ AsymptoticSolve[x + y^2/2 + z/2 + Sin[z] == 0, {z, s1[[3]]}, {{x, y}, {3, -2}, 1}]`. Of course, you can use the other two solutions in `s1` to get two more possible series.

Comment: @J.M.: Thank you. The command `N[%]` should be added in the end in order to obtain a numeric result.